# jQuery Swal using Prevent Default then trigger after confirmation

Tags: jquery, sweetalert2

I am using [sweetalert](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) to trigger the confirmation box before clicking the button and use preventDefault. Is there a way to remove the preventDefault after the confirmation? I've tried trigger click but it keeps on opening the confirmation. This is what I've tried below:

```
function delete_all_product( _e ) {
        _e.preventDefault();
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure you want change region to '+$(this).val()+'?',
            icon: 'info',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
            showCancelButton: true,
            }).then((result) => {
            if (result['isConfirmed']){
                po.populate_product_slider(); 
                $('.product-list-item').remove();
                $(this).trigger('click');// this is what I've added but it keeps on reopening the swal because it triggers everytime I click.                              
            }
        }); 
}

$('input[name="prod_reg"]').click(po.delete_all_product);
```

Comment: Maybe you can add a parameter like `delete_all_product( prevent,_e )` then do `if (prevent) _e.preventDefault();` and then `$(this).trigger('click', [false])`. untested but might work. Also `$('input[name="prod_reg"]').click(po.delete_all_product);` should be `$('input[name="prod_reg"]').click({prevent:true},po.delete_all_product);`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Cool mind! Thank you so much for the logic!

Answer (score 1):

Here are what I've tried. And special thanks to [CarstenLøvboAndersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943218/carsten-l%C3%B8vbo-andersen) for the logic.

```
function delete_all_product( prevent ) {
    if(prevent['data']['prevent'] == true){  
    prevent.preventDefault();
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure you want change region to '+$(this).val()+'?',
        icon: 'info',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        showCancelButton: true,
        }).then((result) => {
        if (result['isConfirmed']){
            prevent['data']['prevent'] = false; // this is to prevent multiple clicks 
            $(this).trigger('click', true); 
            po.populate_product_slider(); 
            $('.product-list-item').remove();
            prevent['data']['prevent'] = true; //this is to make the prevent true again for the next click                              
        }
    }); 
   }else{
        prevent['data']['prevent'] = false; 
   }
}

$('input[name="prod_reg"]').click( {prevent:true}, po.delete_all_product );
```